# How to change Zpanel MySQL root password in Windows 7?

Tags: mysql

I have installed Zpanel in Windows 7. Now I want to change default MySQL root password. But there is no such documentation for changing MySQL root password using Zpanel in Windows 7.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyN46KSfhqU

Comment: That is for wamp, I am using zpanel. There is no mysql5.1.36  in zpanel